# Checking that a provided string is a single path component

Tags: rust

I have a function that accepts a string which will be used to create a file with that name (e.g. `f("foo")` will create a `/some/fixed/path/foo.txt` file). I'd like to prevent users from mistakenly passing strings with `/` separators that would introduce additional sub-directories. Since `PathBuf::push()` accepts strings with multiple components (and, confusingly, so does `PathBuf::set_file_name()`) it doesn't seem possible to prevent pushing multiple components onto a `PathBuf` without a separate check first.

Naively, I could do a `.contains()` check:

```
assert!(!name.contains("/"), "name should be a single path element");
```

But obviously that's not cross-platform. There is [`path::is_separator()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/path/fn.is_separator.html) so I could do:

```
name.chars().any(std::path::is_separator)
```

Alternatively I looked at `Path` for any sort of `is_single_component()` check or similar, I could check the `file_name()` equals the whole path:

```
let name = Path::new(name);
assert_eq!(Some(name.as_os_str()), name.file_name(),
           "name should be a single path element");
```

or that iterating over the path yields one element:

```
assert_eq!(Path::new(name).iter().count(), 1,
           "name should be a single path element");
```

I'm leaning towards this last approach, but I'm just curious if there's a more idiomatic way to ensure pushing a string onto a `PathBuf` will just add one path component.

Comment: `Path::new(name).iter().skip(1).next()` or `Path::new(name).iter().take(2).count()`

Comment: @Stargateur that's fair, but in practice I don't think that optimization is all that beneficial; in the expected case the path will consist of exactly one element, so you'd only waste cycles on the failure case which should be rare (in my case I'll `assert` as its a misuse of the function).

Comment: with one, count call twice next, my code call 2 next or 3 next depend on what code you choice, ok 0 is slower. You ask for more idiomatic not code speed, choice what you want.

Comment: actually `Path::new(name).iter().nth(1).is_some()` is probably more idiom

Comment: Have you tried `Path::parent(&self)` for an alternative ? ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=9ce1711991f3257e31dc65bce44c657e))

Answer (score 1):

If you are fine with limiting yourself to path names that are valid UTF-8, I suggest this succinct implementation:

```
fn has_single_component(path: &str) -> bool {
    !path.contains(std::path::is_separator)
}
```

In contrast to your `Path`-based approaches, it will stop at the first separator found, and it's easy to read.

Note that testing whether a path only consists of a single component is a rather uncommon thing to do, so there isn't a standard way of doing it.

Comment: "testing whether a path only consists of a single component is a rather uncommon thing to do" If you have a `PathBuf` referencing an existing directory and accept an arbitrary string to `push()` onto it, you need to know the structure of that string in order to know whether, for example, you need to create intermediate directories below the original path (or, as I want to do, reject that string).

Comment: I agree this isn't specially uncommon. As soon as you have to implement features like autocomplete or just try to copy any standard linux utility like scp, you notice how lacking is the Path API.